# WSO2 API Manager API WSDL

Tags: api, wso2, wso2-esb

We are publishing a SOAP service using WSO2 API Manager. I have a question regarding the service WSDL, when we specify the API WSDL URL it has the original end point address instead of the API Manager end point address, is there a way to have the published API with a WSDL having API Manager end point?

Comment: Usually, it is the original end point address. Can I know what is your use case?

Comment: Our use case is just like the use case mentioned below, we don't want the consumer to know about the back-end endpoint.

Comment: Did you solve this? I have the same issue. I would like to have wsdl2java generate code that uses the API via the API manager. The end-point is not reachable directly for the SOAP client and should be accessed via the API manager but the wsdlsoap:address location is not correct.

Comment: No, with the latest version(that I tried, v1.6) they generate a WSDL for you but it didn't have the full path of the API just the base of the gateway.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, While creating an API you should provide the sample soap service wsdl (ex:SOAP WSDL - https://ws.cdyne.com/phoneverify/phoneverify.asmx?wsdl). after completing the design provide the production endpoint (ex: Production Endpoint -https://ws.cdyne.com/phoneverify/phoneverify.asmx) and published the api. Go to api store and there is an option to download the wsdl generated from apim. It is pointing to API Manager end point.

[1] https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM191/Invoke+an+API+using+a+SOAP+Client

[2] http://blog.rajkumarr.com/2015/08/how-to-expose-soap-services-as-soap-services-via-wso2-api-manager.html